# converting VS2010 to VS 2015, C1189 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am converting my project VS2010 to VS2015
and face on error C1189 "#error: Macro definition of vsnprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration"
this file is stdio.h
how can I resolve this?

Comment: Check if the include paths of your project are correct - I suspect that for some reason you have VC++2010 leftovers in there.

Comment: vsnprintf is available in STD from C++11, VS2010 support C++11 partially. maybe Someone define (maybe Microsoft) and using it without error. But VS2015 support C++11 better and you see this error.

Comment: thx for your helping